# Nested selects in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view

**Setting**:

Each page on my site has four widgets that are arranged in different orders (1-4).
I have a table 'content' and table 'widgets'. I have a bridging table that maps `content`.id to `widgets`.content_id.

**Problem**:

What I want to do is run a query that `selects * from content along with addition columns widget_1, widget_2, widget_3, widget_4, each containing the id of the widget linked to that page.`

I've been trying some nested selects all morning and can't seem to crack it. I've copied the MySQL dumps of the involved tables below :-).

```
CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `permalink` varchar(64) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `title` varchar(128) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `content` text character set latin1,
  `content_type` varchar(16) NOT NULL default 'page',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`content`,`meta_description`,`meta_keywords`)
)


CREATE TABLE `widgets` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `text` varchar(256) default NULL,
  `image` varchar(128) default NULL,
  `target` varchar(128) default NULL,
  `code` varchar(32) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `content_widgets` (
  `content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `widget_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
)
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: there is no `meta_description`,`meta_keywords` in table `content` and u write

    FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`content`,`meta_description`,`meta_keywords`)

Comment: what means by `widget1,widget2 etc`.. do u want to show all column of widget or a single column containing `widget.id`

Comment: ah, don't mind the meta bits; I stripped out a few fields from the content table to keep it concise. I'd like a single column containing widget.id. So widget_1 of page #3 would be SELECT widget_id FROM content_widgets WHERE content_id = 3 AND `order` = 1, widget_2 would be SELECT widget_id FROM content_widgets WHERE content_id = 3 AND `order` = 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested query - just a join. Assuming that you want to start with a content record and return the matching widgets....

```
SELECT c.*, w.*
FROM content c
   LEFT JOIN (
      content_widgets cw INNER JOIN widgets w
      ON cw.widget_id=w.id
   ) ON c.id=cw.id
WHERE c.id=....
```

Although a simple innter join is a better idea of you know you've got the widgets:

```
SELECT c.*, w.*
FROM content c, content_widgets cw widgets w
WHERE cw.widget_id=w.id
AND c.id=cw.id
AND c.id=....
```